# sqlite-net is not able to recognize primary keys from parent class

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

I have my class `FileDownloadContentModel` which extends `IBaseContentModel`

```
 public class FileDownloadContentModel : IBaseContentModel
 {

    public string url { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public int downloadPercentage { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateDownloaded { get; set; }
    public byte[] content { get; set; }
 }
```

Here is `IBaseContentModel`:

```
 public class IBaseContentModel
 {
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public IBaseContentModel()
    {
        id = GenerateID();
    }

    protected static int GenerateID()
    {
        DateTime value = DateTime.UtcNow;
        //create Timespan by subtracting the value provided from the Unix Epoch
        TimeSpan span = (value - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime());
        //return the total seconds (which is a UNIX timestamp)
        return (int)span.TotalSeconds;
    }
 }
```

For some reason sqlite-net is unable to recognize the primary key when it is getting the table mappings. It states that the primary key is null. If I include the id (primary key) directly in my `FileDownloadContentModel` class, it is able to recognize the primary key as id.

Is this is a known bug or am I doing something wrong here? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

**UPDATED**

I looked into it more right now and its a stupid mistake on my part. I have two "instances" of sqlite and for some reason IBaseContentModel was using a different instance of sqlite than FileDownloadContentModel which is why the primary key was not being recognized (because it wasn't from the same instance). And by instance i mean two completely different sqlite.cs files with different package names.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem with the exact code you have given above. When I try to insert/ delete, SQLite-Net finds the primary key. Is it possible that your base is actually an interface, as @RoadBump suggested in his answer?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it chue x. I looked into it more right now and its a stupid mistake on my part. I have two "instances" of sqlite and for some reason IBaseContentModel was using a different instance of sqlite than FileDownloadContentModel which is why the primary key was not being recognized (because it wasn't from the same instance). And by instance i mean two completely different sqlite.cs files with different package names.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the normal behavior of .NET. A interface is not really inherited, it just forces you to implement its contract. The implementation is standalone and inherits nothing from the interface.
Thats why the following test fails:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestProject2
{
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        [Description("Test Attribute")]
        void Member();
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class Class1 : IMyInterface
    {
        public void Member()
        {

        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestAttributeInheritance()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Checking interface attribute");
            MethodInfo info = typeof(IMyInterface).GetMethod("Member");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true).Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Checking implementation attribute");
            info = typeof(Class1).GetMethod("Member");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true).Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Checking interface attribute  
Checking implementation attribute  
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<1>. Actual:<0>.
```

Comment: This may be true if the base were an interface; however, if you look at the code above, the base is a class. However, it is indeed possible that the actual code is an interface, and that the OP has mistyped it here.

Comment: Hadn't noticed it, the class name is really misleading... let's see what the OP says.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I have mistyped the class name as 'IBaseContentModel' instead of 'BaseContentModel', my base is a class and not an interface. But it is good to know that it wouldn't work for an interface. Hopefully your answer will help others who run into that problem.

Comment: I looked into it more right now and its a stupid mistake on my part. I have two "instances" of sqlite and for some reason IBaseContentModel was using a different instance of sqlite than FileDownloadContentModel which is why the primary key was not being recognized (because it wasn't from the same instance). And by instance i mean two completely different sqlite.cs files with different package names.